# Proving that a certain set in a generic forcing extension was already in the ground model

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $M[G]$ is a generic extension of a model $M$. Consider a cardinal $\lambda$ with a    partial order $\leq\in M[G]$ and   let $\mathscr D$ be a collection  of $\lambda$ dense sets of $\langle\lambda, \leq\rangle$.  In particular, let $\mathscr D=\{D_\alpha:\alpha\in\lambda \}$. Suppose that the set $X=\{\langle\alpha, \beta \rangle\}\in \lambda\times\lambda:\beta\in D_\alpha\}$ is  already in $M$.

How can I define $\mathscr D$ in terms of $X$ in such a way that it will imply $\mathscr D$ is also in $M$?

Just for reference, it is related to  the proof of the consistency of Martin's Axiom as it appears in Kunen's book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f\colon X\to\lambda$ by $f(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha$, then $f$ is in $M$. Now the preimage function $f^{-1}(\alpha)=\{\alpha\}\times D_\alpha$, now you can prove that $Y=\{\{\alpha\}\times D_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}\in M$. Finally, consider the map from $Y$ such that $(\alpha,D_\alpha)$ is mapped to $D_\alpha$, it too is definable in $M$ therefore its range, $\{D_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}\in M$ as wanted.

Comment: Thanks, actually my problem was that I was  totally forgetting the replacement schema.

Comment: Yeah, it's sometimes easy to forget about it.